# Change ST_Intersects default tolerance

Tags: postgis, sql, st-intersects

The default tolerance of PostGIS ST_Intersects query is "0.00001 meters" as indicated in the [doc](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html). I need to use the same query with another tolerance value but ST_Intersects takes only 2 input parameters (geom A and geom B).

Is there a way to change this default value?

Comment: Have you checked this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157092/set-tolerance-in-postgis ?

Comment: Yes I have checked this discussion, and have tried ST_Dwithin but it takes much more time than ST_Intersects

Comment: There is solution but not straightforward, PostGIS is opensource so you can update the value and compile https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/c0998a4e638048196a6abfab1504eca6b1a1462f/postgis/geography.sql.in#L720

Comment: Use ST_SnapToGrid first, which effectively rounds the geometries, before ST_Intersects. Note, ST_Intersects and ST_Within are not the same thing, and the latter has to do more work, so would take longer.

Comment: Or do what @Shika says, it is OSS, after all :-)

Comment: Yes ! I like the solution of @Shika
thank to all of you

Comment: @AdamAdam Did you manage to use the dynamic tolerance ?  
I've updated my answer

Comment: This is not a duplicate, because this is about the `geography` type, which does use a tolerance.  The linked question is about the `geometry` type which does not.  Please don't vote to close questions that you don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PostGIS** is opensource, indeed you can create a new function for ST_INTERSECT with **Tolerance** parameter as input or update the function itself with value you are interested in, then run it.
Here is the code snippet where tolerance is dynamic, you can run below script in your DB and it will be create under PUBLIC schema :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_Intersects(geography, geography,float8)
    RETURNS boolean
    AS 'SELECT $1 && $2 AND _ST_Distance($1, $2, 0.0, false) < $3'
    LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE ;
```

**Link for original function of ST_Intersects(geo,geo):**
https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/c0998a4e638048196a6abfab1504eca6b1a1462f/postgis/geography.sql.in#L720

Comment: Except either remove `@extschema@.` or replace it with the extension schema e.g. `public`

Comment: @MikeT Thanks, I updated to public and rectify the function.

Comment: @Shiko thank you for the detailed reply. I have not tested the solution yet.
I have another problem with GEOS (self-intersection and OGC Simple Feature specification..)
I'll give the result as soon as possible

Comment: I did this :  ``CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.st_intersects(geometry, geometry, double precision)
  RETURNS boolean AS
'SELECT $1 OPERATOR(public.&&) $2 AND public._ST_Distance($1, $2, 0.0, false) < $3'
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE``   I got this error message when I launch a query:   ``Only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in geography``   Note that my data are in metric projection

Comment: Sorry I did not manage to format my comment

Comment: Unfortunately I have just realized and as @dbaston said, the 0.00001 tolerance value is only for Geography, and I can't find any information about tolerance for Geometry.